# How do I change the background color on only the ALL columns and rows for a Crosstab report in JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I have created a Crosstab report in JasperReports and would like to add some conditional coloring to only the ALL rows and columns. 
So far I have attempted to check for the `<Measure>_<Column Group>_ALL` variables in a conditional style, but this doesn't work when some of the values are the same as the values in the ALL row/columns.
I am using the `ROW_COUNT` variable to do alternating row colors, but I noticed that it doesn't count the ALL row as a discrete row.
Is this possible?

[image: crosstab]

I want the background color for the data in the average columns/rows to be grey in the above example without messing up the alternating row color.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean with only the "ALL" columns and rows (TotalRowHeader?), image of what you like to achieve could help as some relevant jrxml

Comment: I am talking about the average columns. I don't have any jrxml because the report is pure java. I added an image to the original question.

Comment: This is going to be almost impossible to answer since no code base. However I imagine that now the average column is part of your datasource... the trick would be to make a crosstabCell with columnTotalGroup attribute and then set the style you like to this

Comment: setRowTotalGroup and setColumnTotalGroup worked perfectly! Thanks. If you reply with an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Ok I have posted an answer, you may edit if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set specific style to a column group it needs to be outside of your datasource. Add a `crosstabCell` where you set the `columnTotalGroup` and on this set style as you like.

**jrxml code**

```
<crosstabCell width="50" height="28" columnTotalGroup="myColumnGroup">
     <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
       <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
       </box>
       <textField>
            <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="11" width="50" height="16" forecolor="#000000" uuid="27bcff56-8b7a-4867-b1bb-f0f35f750525"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
              <font size="8"/>
              <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{myAverage})]]></textFieldExpression>
       </textField>
    </cellContents>
</crosstabCell>
```

To get the cell's after the data set `totalPosition="End"` on the group

You can apply this also for rows totals using `setRowTotalGroup`